# Overloaded operator isn't usable with the class it was defined for

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have overloaded the operator "-" to take two objects of a class and output a new one, however when I use it eg. obj3 = obj1 - obj2, I get an error saying no operator matches these operands.

The declaration of the namespace inside vctmath.h:

```
#ifndef VCTMATH
#define VCTMATH
namespace vctmath {
    Vect operator -(Vect a, Vect b);
}
#endif
```

The definition inside the main vctmath file;

```
#include "Vect.h"
#include "vctmath.h"
Vect vctmath::operator -(Vect a, Vect b) {
    Vect output(0);
    output.SetX(a.GetX() - b.GetX());
    return output;
}
```

This is the class declaration in the Vect.h file

```
#ifndef VECT
#define VECT

class Vect {
private:
    float x;
public:
    Vect(float);
    const float GetX(void);
    void SetX(float a);
};
#endif
```

And this is the definition of Vect in Vect.cpp:

```
#include "Vect.h"
#include "vctmath.h"

Vect::Vect(float a): x(a) {}
const float Vect::GetX(void) { return x; };
void Vect::SetX(float a) {
    x = a;
}
```

The main function creates two objects of the Vect class then attempts to use the newly overloaded - operator:

```
#include "Vect.h"
#include "vctmath.h"
int main() {
    Vect vect1(0);
    Vect vect2(1);
    Vect vect3 = vect1 - vect2; //this is where the problem is
    return 0;
}
```

The error is E0349; no operator "-" matches these operands,
operand types are Vect - Vect.

Comment: Present your [mcve].

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Whoops :P

Comment: That's still not a [mcve]. But it's closer. At least we can see the problem now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit now it seems to be a problem with namespace. I was correct with my intuition. :P

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Yeah sorry about that lol. I had no idea you could qualify a function definition like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is not going to search in a random namespace for an operator overload of a type which is in the global namespace.

There is no relation between `Vect` and `vctmath` namespace hence the compiler is not able to find the overload you want to use.

You can either:

- open the namespace before using operators: `using namespace vctmath`
- move `Vect` to the namespace
- define the operator as a member method, `Vect::operator-`

Comment: The second bullet point is the normal solution.  The third option is poor.

Comment: @M.M: the third solution is not poor under all circumstances. It really depends on your type and how you're going to use it. Unless you need to overload operations with fundamental types, eg `float + Vect` then there is not much practical difference between the two

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear how you defined Vect. Apparently in the code you shown that the problem now is in visibility of names inside namespace. It's recommended that you explicitely use namespace names when you use classes defined in namespaces.

I recommend you change the Vector.h (and .cpp accordingly):

```
... 
namespace vctmath {
    class Vect {
    ...
    };       
} // namespace vctmath
....
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    vctmath::Vect vect1(0);
    vctmath::Vect vect2(1);
    Vect vect3 = vect1 - vect2;
    return 0;
}
```

If by some reason you would not like to place Vect into namespace you have other options:
a) call operator explicitely:

```
Vect vect3 = vctmath::operator-(vect1, vect2);
```

b) use an adapter design pattern:

```
Vect operator -(Vect& a, Vect& b) {
    return vctmath::operator-(a, b);
}

int main() {
    Vect vect1(0);
    Vect vect2(1);
    Vect vect3 = vect1 - vect2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok my mistake I had no idea you could qualify a function definition with its namespace name like that!

Comment: I suggest putting `Vect` in the namespace too so ADL can find the operator. Would you like to add this to your answer?